# Finding aggregate of time from different instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, aggregate

I have a model called WorkInterval which records contain basically:

```
start_date, end_date
```

I would like to be able to get all the WorkIntervals for a particular Task (I know how to deal with the association) and get the total time spent.  So, do the aggregation (addition) of all the differences between end_date and start_date (end_date - start_date for all the instances.

Right now I am able to do this:

`@task.work_intervals` -> Which gives me all the work_intervals, but how could I get the sum of the time spend on that task in a clean ruby way?

Notice:

1 - both end_date and start_date are **DateTime**. 
2 - Some instances might have the end_date as NIL, If that is the case, the current datetime should be taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@task.work_intervals
.map {|i| (i.end_date || Time.now).to_time - i.start_date.to_time }
.reduce(:+)
# => total in seconds
```

Comment: dbenhur, thanks for the answer.  I am sorry I just edited the question because it might be that some work_intervals have the end_date as nil, and those which have it as NIL, should take as end_date the current date.

Comment: Then do: `{|i| i.end_date || DateTime.now - i.start_date }`

Comment: dbenhur why doing the .to_time ? If I already have DateTime instances?

Comment: @HommerSmith because subracting `Time`s produces seconds as `Fixnum`, but subtracting `DateTime`s produces days as `Rational`.

Comment: @HommerSmith `ruby -rdate -e'puts (DateTime.now - DateTime.now).class'` => `Rational` (under rubies 2.0.0, 1.9.3, 1.8.7). Perhaps you have some library that's monkeypatching `DateTime#-`, but rational is the default behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a tip, in your Task model def a function like this:

```
def total_time_in_hours
 _total_time = 0
 self.work_intervals.each do |work_interval|
  _start_date = work_interval.start_date
  _end_date = work_interval.end_date
  _end_date = Time.now unless _end_date.blank?
  _total_time += ((_end_date - _start_date)/1.hour).round
 end
 _total_time
end
```

now access the total time like this `@any_task.total_time_in_hours`... hope that helps... :)

[UPDATE]

Ignore this answer, I made some mistakes... :(

My test was done with an actual record of my database in posgresql, the table column was initialy created as datetime, but I don't kow if something changes when I retrieve a record in Rails...

```
1.8.7-p371 :001 > @init_date = MaterialReservacion.first.hora_limite

  => Thu, 11 Apr 2013 19:09:14 CDT -05:00

1.8.7-p371 :002 > @end_date = Time.now

  => Fri Apr 12 09:33:34 -0500 2013 

1.8.7-p371 :003 > ((@end_date-@init_date)/1.hour).round
  => 14
```

Comment: Damn, that's some ugly Ruby. Use 2-space indents, avoid `_` vars when you don't need them, skip the gratuitous `self`, use appropriate enum methods instead of each and an accumulator. Also, it doesn't work. You can't subtract a `DateTime` from a `Time` and you've failed to actually accumulate the values.

Comment: uumm sorry I wrote the code right in the answer, and it does gives you the hours since de start date to the end date, obiously as an integer, if you want the days spend use 1.day... and I tried the subtraccion already, I'm wouldn't post an answer if I'm not sure about what to do...

Comment: Are you evaluating code indenting now? or are you looking for an answer?

Comment: Jose: don't make excuses. I'm obviously not looking for an answer, I supplied a better one (style & correctness) hours before yours. Even with your edit (which should have been in place, not a postscript), your code sample will still throw a TypeError when end date is blank. If you're so thin-skinned that you must whine when offered constructive criticism perhaps you shouldn't offer code examples to the public?

Comment: Well, I'm sorry for trying to help, obviuosly I'm not an expert in Rails, and I'm not interested in gaining reputation, but when someone ask for help and I can provide something I do it, I have proven this in my console

Comment: `irb> require 'date'; Time.now - DateTime.now` => "TypeError: can't convert DateTime into an exact number"